# C# to VB - how to replicate a function structure

Tags: c#, vb.net, function

I'm mostly a VB developer, but I know some C#. A while back I put together a C# program designed to extract the text body from an Outlook email using mostly c# code that I copied from some website. That has worked great for years.

Now I have a VB application that needs the same functionality, and I was hoping to be able translate it over from C#. I'm having a problem with the difference in structure for a function in VB vs C#.

The C# code is:

```
  private static bool CertificateValidationCallBack(
        object sender,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
        System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
      {
       [rest of the function]

 Return bit
      }
```

The calling line is:

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
```

which, as can be seen, does not include the four parameters that the function seems to require. Yet it still works.

Translating it to a VB function, absent the four parameters will, naturally, show an error in the code.

What am I missing?

Comment: It doesn't include the parameters because you are assigning a *delegate* not invoking the method. Something similar should would in VB

Comment: You're trying to assign a delegate, not call the function. Try `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf CertificateValidationCallBack` in VB.NET.

Comment: `return` is correct not `Return`! C# is case sensitive.

Comment: @Hussein Golshani Thanks. I was just typing that by hand.

Comment: @PMColtrane That worked!  It doesn't show up as an error now. But I'll bet I'll hit a few more similar roadblocks. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @pmcoltrane you should write that as an answer

Comment: If you just need the callback to return `True`, you could use an inline Function: `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(s, Ca, CaC, sslPE)   Return True   End Function`

Comment: @pmcoltrane That's the one that worked!

Comment: I suspect that VB.NET requires `AddressOf` in order to distinguish between a reference to a method, and the call to the method, because in VB.NET method invocation doesn't require parentheses. In C#, since method invocation requires parentheses, without parentheses it's a reference to the method.

Answer (score 0):

VB Syntax:

```
Private Shared Function CertificateValidationCallBack(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certificate As X509Certificate, ByVal chain As X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

Usage: (it is delegate and you should specify function's address)

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf CertificateValidationCallBack)
```

Comment: Or, the shorter syntax: ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf CertificateValidationCallBack

Comment: @Hussein Golshani Thanks, but that one wouldn't pass VB's syntax checker. The line from pmcoltrane was the one that worked.